# Является ли паттерн проектирования "Strategy" составной частью других паттернов?

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, шаблоны, шаблон-стратегия

В последнее время ловлю себя на мысли о том, что паттерн проектирования "Стратегия" является обычным проявлением полиморфизма и используется во многих других паттернах.
Напомню диаграмму "Стратегии":
[image: Диаграмма паттерна "Strategy"]

А теперь о том, в каких именно паттернах используется "Стратегия".

Абстрактная фабрика. По сути, иерархия фабрик является стратегией, клиент использует тот или иной фабричный метод в зависимости от ситуации.
[image: Стратегия в паттерне "Абстрактная фабрика"]

Мост. Иерархия реализации может представлять из себя комбинацию из базового класса и двух или более производных классов, которые реализуют одну операцию по-разному:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более того, стратегию можно обнаружить в таких шаблонах, как Mediator (если существует иерархия классов, объекты которых взаимодействуют друг с другом), Proxy, Prototype и других.

Вопрос в том, насколько верна такая интерпретация, что "Стратегия" - это иерархия классов с переопределением какого-либо алгоритма? Ведь если данная интерпретация верна, то около половины GOF-паттернов могут включать в себя "Стратегию". И, кстати, некоторые из них (к примеру, тот же "Мост") используют тот или иной алгоритм в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: Не является он никаким полиморфизмом. Просто использует это полиморфизм для своих целей где это возможно. И не похож он ни на фабрику, ни на мост. Клиент выбирает метод фабрики, но стратегию задать может вообще какая-то другая часть программы, и от клиента, вообще говоря, ничего не зависит. И медиатором никаким не является. Стратегия свой собственный алгоритм представляет, а не третьей стороны.

Comment: @Sergey И метод фабрики может быть выбран не клиентом, и стратегия может быть выбрана клиентом. В медиаторе я говорил про тот случай, когда есть несколько взаимодействующих классов, реализующих общий интерфейс, и медиатор выбирает стратегию (с кем взаимодействовать)

Comment: Фабрика служит для получения каких-то там объектов. И медиатор тоже служит конкретной задачи - быть медиатором между тем-то и тем-то. Стратегия же - выбор алгоритма для произвольной задачи. Одна стратегия `print мяу-мяу`, другая `print гав-гав`. Не возвращают никакой объект, не представляют какой-то третий объект. Для реализации фабрика, медиатора и мало ли ещё чего можно применить стратегию, с соответствующими алгоритмами, если надо. А на схемах всё выглядит одинаково. Квадратики, стрелочки - они и в Африке квадратики.

Answer (score 3):

Я не могу дать точного ответа на Ваш вопрос, но могу подтолкнуть к ожидаемому ответу.

В шаблоне проектирование **"Стратегия"** в основе лежит способ добавления-подмены объектов во время выполнения программы. Возможно минимальный пример **Стратегия** наилучшим образом иллюстрирует этот принцип и по этому его отражение Вы и видите в других шаблонах. Но на самом деле у этого архитектурного решения есть более низкоуровневое абстрактное определение и называется оно **"Агрегация"**.

Наверняка все знакомы с **"Композицией"**, это когда объект внутри себя создает нужные ему объекты. Так вот **"Агрегация"**, это когда объект получает свои зависимости из внешнего мира. И этот принцип является одним из столпов приличного программирования. Ведь та же **банда четырех** в своей книге говорит что композиция предпочтительней наследованию. Но существует так же выражение что агрегация предпочтительней композиции.

Возможно понимание того что **"Стратегия"** описывает более низкоуровневые принципы программирования и является причиной того, что она повсюду?

Comment: Я думаю, что это действительно более "низкоуровневый" шаблон, как и Фасад, к примеру, который так же можно увидеть в большинстве паттернов.

Comment: Дело в том что Фасад это реализация принципа сокрытия. То есть есть принцип-закон программирования, а реализация- воплощение этого закона в коде, это Фасад. То же самое и с Стратегией, это реализация принципа агрегации.

Comment: Какая там замена классов? Замена - по-моему неудачный термин. Вообще говоря, изначально даже может не быть какого-то предопределённого класса. Значит и заменять нечего. Стратегия позволяет назначить тот или иной алгоритм. А то, что при этом что-то там заменится - это побочный эффект.